# Why does toString() works even without any object or string to call upon

Tags: javascript, tostring

Noticed something in a codebase that I am working on.

If you just execute `toString()` without any object to call upon it just works!

Initially I thought this must be the result of  implicit call on the `window` object but it wasn't as apparent from this

```js
alert(toString())
```

```js
alert(window.toString())
```

Both return different results so therefore must run on different entities, So how does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same function:

```
window.toString === toString  // true
```

reason is, if you invoke on `window`, then the `this` is `window`.

Now, you may wonder, well, if `toString()` is run as is, then shouldn't `this` be the global object, which is `window` too?  It should be due to the code of `toString()` is running in "strict" mode, which means the `this` will be `undefined`.

Try in a browser like Google Chrome:

```js
function foo() { 
  "use strict"; 
  console.log(this);
}

function bar() {  
  console.log(this);
}

foo();
bar();
```

and now, if `this` is `undefined`, then by the [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring):

> If the this value is undefined, return "[object Undefined]".